# [FL Studio]: Is it possible to map notes?

Tags: fl-studio

I have a problem with my new drum VST. I can't really recognize some of drum parts (because I'm not a drummer) and I need something like FPC which has the name of that part in the piano roll. 
My new vst came with a drm and txt file which are for cubase and reaper, and not FL Studio. Is it possible to have a "drum note map" in FL studio for non-native plugins?